# How would I split the contents of a JSON file and then show user tags instead of ID's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a list admins command for a bot, and I'm struggling to convert user ids to tags through the command. Here's what I have so far:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { readFileSync, existsSync } = require('fs');

module.exports = {
 name: 'list-admins',
 async execute(msg, args) {
  if (
   ['430437160613707796', '321332200668790786', '329220047824486400'].indexOf(
    msg.author.id
   ) === -1
  )
   return msg.channel.send(
    new MessageEmbed()
     .setColor('RED')
     .setDescription(`**You are not an owner**`)
     .setTimestamp()
   );

  try {
   var object = JSON.parse(readFileSync('admins.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }));
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }

  var adminss = JSON.stringify(object);
  var synadmin = await adminss.split(`\n`);

  if (existsSync(`admins.json`)) {
   let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Synergy-V Admins`)
    .setColor('f3f3f3')
    .setDescription(`**${synadmin}**`);

   msg.channel.send(embed);
  }
 },
};
```

And here's the contents of the `admins.json` file:

```json
{
 "321332200668790786": true,
 "430437160613707796": true,
 "329220047824486400": true,
 "432158415528394762": true,
 "478475107833085952": true,
 "422244702608424961": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const object = { // get the object however you want
  "321332200668790786": true, 
  "430437160613707796": true, 
  "329220047824486400": true, 
  "432158415528394762": true, 
  "478475107833085952": true, 
  "422244702608424961": true
};

const tags = Object.keys(object); // `Object.keys()` returns an array with every key
tags.map(id => message.client.users.cache.get(id).tag) // map the array to get the tags

console.log(tags.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be an error when you read and stringify the `admins.json` file, try to remove the bools.

Also you have to respect the format `"<@" + USER_ID + ">"` to get the tags from the ids.

Comment: I cannot remove the bools, as that would break the admin system, Perhaps it would be beneficial to showcase the output:
https://www.system-exodus.com/u/EAX6FNWZMt.png